# Creating custom language in PhpStorm that EXTEND all html language features

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, phpstorm

Is it possible to create a custom language in PhpStorm that extends HTML language.
I want to add CoffeeScript and Mammouth support to HTML. something like this:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Second</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>{{ echo 'mammouth' }}</p>
  <script>
    alert 'Hello CoffeScript!'
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which will be compile to:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Second</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p><?php echo "mammouth"; ?></p>
  <script>
    alert ('Hello CoffeScript!');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript is already supported by IntelliJ platform, please learn more on [the official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/coffeescript-support.html). As to Mammouth you can use handy [Custom Language Support Tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) and [IntelliJ Platform SDK Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html) to study how to create your own plugin.